# Чем данный вопрос заслужил правки?

Tags: обсуждение

Привет, мета!

Чем [данный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715502/python-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) заслужил правки?

Я задал вопрос для того, чтобы решить проблему, не имея представления как его решить. Задал максимально коротко и без приветствий, как тут это любят. Вопрос полезный для базы знаний, а также логичный для поисковой системы.

Если кто-то бомбит от того, что могут порекомендовать не его любимую библиотеку, это его проблемы, если вы не знаете ответа и поэтому вы голосуете за закрытие — опять же, это ваша проблема.

Это ресурс-база знаний, а в итоге я трачу время на оспаривание не пойми чего, а не на решение своей задачи.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: База знаний и "каталог бибилиотечек" - разные вещи. Спросили бы "как в питоне распознать номер" - и вопрос бы никто не тронул.

Comment: @PashaPash прочитай вопрос и ознакомься что такое каталог, а потом пиши комментарий. А, так вот в чём дело? Нужно просто ставить вопрос по-другому? Не какой библиотекой пользоваться, а как мне это реализовать? С ума сойти

Comment: прочитай хелп, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, кусок "Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать", а потом задавай вопросы на мете

Comment: да, нужно ставить вопрос по-другому. тут так принято. потому что если попросить ссылку - начинают кидать ссылки. открой любой старый вопрос про "найти плагин jquery" и оцени качество ответов

Comment: @PashaPash я сказал, что желателен ответ в таком формате, но он вовсе не обязателен.

Comment: так это единственный возможный формат для "Требуется библиотека для распознавания телефонных номеров из картинки" :)

Comment: @PashaPash *__Приветствуется ответ в формате:__*

- ссылка на библиотеку
- ссылка на документацию к ней

__`Блок кода с примером реализации`__

Comment: @PashaPash это вполне достойный ответ на вопрос о библиотеке для базы знаний

Comment: @Grundy, ничего, что там с +7 победил ответ _разрешить_? Иди, переоткрывай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в том ответе было про наличие четких критериев, в текущем вопросе - критериев нет вообще, просто библиотека.

Comment: @Qwertiy может он там и победил - но в правилах все равно вписано "оффтопик". ну и к тому же - зачем принудительно сводить вопрос к "киньте в меня библиотекой?", если можно было обойтись без этого?

Comment: @Qwertiy я понимаю что очень хочется расширить офтопик и переоткрыть - но напоминаю что использовать открытие / закрытие стоит для поддержания правил, а не "потому что так захотелось!". Переоткрывать оффтопик - нарушение правил.

Comment: @PashaPash в чём оффтопик-то? Объясни конкретно

Comment: @KitScribe https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - там есть отдельный раздел про оффтопик. в нем прямо сказано, что у нас оффтопичны "Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.". Достаточно конкретно?

Comment: @PashaPash цитирую: "Вопросы о том, **где** найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию."

Comment: @PashaPash мой вопрос о том, какая библиотека решает мою задачу. То есть я пытаюсь сократить время себе и другим людям, корректно используя базу знаний. Не вижу оффтопика

Comment: @KitScribe ок, давайте копать формулировки. вы попросили ссылку на "где"? - значит попали в оффтопик. Я уже написал выше, дважды - если у вас задача "распознать картинку", то вопрос стоило задать в виде "как распознать картинку". А не в виде "подскажите библиотеку для распознавания картинок." и не в виде "подскажите хорошую статью о распознавании картинок".

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос должен сводится к формулировке проблемы. а ответы - к ее решению. Сейчас вопрос сводится не к решению проблемы, а к переписи библиотек. Т.е. он сформулирован так, что требует ответа-ссылки. Хотя сама по себе оригинальная проблема вполне онтопична. Проблема хорошая, вопрос - плохой. Он сформулирован так, что вместо ответа с развернумым решением проблемы предлагает публиковать ответы-ссылки (которые приводят потом к трешу в очередях)

Answer (score 3):

Моё мнение: вопрос нужно переоткрыть, поскольку причина его закрытия чисто формальна. Очевидно, что решений, не использующих библиотеки, никто на вопрос такой сложности не напишет, поэтому нет смысла придираться к тому, что формулировка не даёт возможности постить решения, не требующие использования библиотек.

Переписка с @PashaPash в чате:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39869223#39869223
заканчивается так:

> **P:** да, это формальная придирка к формулировке
>
> **Q:** ну так я и считаю, что формальные придирки не нужны, поэтому вопорс стоит держать открытым :)
>
> **P:** пусть исправит формулировку - с удовольствием переоткрою
> и даже плюсану. может быть.

Comment: Переоткрыл, плюсанул